# button.setId(integer value) gives me view error

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi all i have implemented my customized simpleCursorAdapter and its view merged with another view to create my desired page but when i try to set id to each button of my list view's record than it is giving me an view error

Half of the logic is from this link:

[http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

and other part of code of my customize view is given below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.fr1);


        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
                startManagingCursor(c);
                String[] cols = new String[]{People.NAME};
                int[] names = new int[]{R.id.FriendsName};

        SimpleCursorAdapter rows = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.flistview,c,cols,names);
        setListAdapter(rows);           
    }

public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public DisplayFriendsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageButton Btn1 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
            Btn1.setId(position);
            ImageButton Btn2 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.Button2);
            Btn2.setId(position);
            Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Accepted", "clicked"+v.getId());

                }
            }); 

            Btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                }
            }); 
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now when i try to setContentView(R.layout.fr1) in onCreate() method and Btn1.setId(position), it gives me an error, y so? and as i said earlier i have merged 2 views means 1 view for my cursorAdapter and other which contains searchBox and ListView as shown in above link

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the button's ID. It's ID is already defined in the `XML` for the UI and placed as a constant in `R.java` as `R.id.Button1`. Just delete those `.setID(...)` lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for responding but than how will i detect that this particular button of particular record is pressed, hop u getting, see i have to place friends list in place of contacts in above example and than on click on particular friend's record button i have to show his other details, tel me what should i do?

Comment: Okay let me come this way see, i have number of friends and i have listed them in cusomized SimpleCursorAdapter as shown above, now this data will be provided by server and server will provide me each everyone's user_id which i have to attach so when user click on any record's detail button, i can tell server this user-id record has been clicked and i want his info, and than redirect user to next page, so now how can i distinguish. thanks once again for replying

Comment: when i click on any of btn1 from the list it gives me 2131034138 clicked(by View.getId()) and on click of other button of the list returns me id 2131034138, so i am not able to distinguish between records, which record is selected.